# My google cloud console dashboard theme is changed. how to revert?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

it's been few weeks that my GCP console dashboard theme is changed into this:
[image: current theme]
It's like 95% color is only white. I really dont like how it's look. Please help to change back the theme. Or is it somekind of bug?

normal theme using other account:
[image: normal theme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not a bug**. It's their new **update** and they have been rolling it out for a couple months now.

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/xwheef/comment/ir6ftcc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: i see, but it's not affecting to all users yet? @Jordi

Comment: Not affecting all projects yet, no.